# Map column value to table name and join

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a composite type that looks like

```
CREATE TYPE member AS (
    id BIGINT,
    type CHAR(1)
);
```

I have a table that relies on this `member` type with an array.

```
CREATE TABLE relation (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    members member[]
);
```

I have three other tables each with a different schema (but having common `id` field)

```
CREATE TABLE table_x (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_text TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE table_y (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_int INT
);

CREATE TABLE table_z (
    id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    some_date TIMESTAMP
);
```

`type` field in `member` type is just one character to find out table that specific member belongs to. A row in `relation` table can have a mix of different `type`s.

I have a scenario which requires returning `relation` ids with at least one `member` fulfilling a certain condition based on it's type (let's say for `x` => `some_text` is not empty or `y` => `some_int` is greater than 10 or `z` => `some_date` is a week is from now).

I can implement this scenario on the application side by making multiple requests to the database:

- unnest `relation` table
- collect `member` data per `relation`
- make new requests to find out `relation`s

I am wondering if there is a way to map column values to table names and join them.

Comment: Do you have sample data and expected result?

Comment: This sounds like not-so-great database design since we are getting into dynamic table names territory. There is no way in a single query to say "Use the value from a field in this one table to get the table name to which I am to join, join to it, and select the data". Although if you can explain withe xamples what you are needing, perhaps there is some workaround where you join all of the tables and coalesce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JNevill had a good point about this database design. Although this approach may not seem optimal, it keeps the table definitions clearly separate without any relations in between them. Also the size of `relation` table is fairly small compared to other three tables.

I solved the problem by simply fetching rows per type and merging them:

```
SELECT relation.* FROM relation, UNNEST(relation.members) member INNER JOIN table_x ON member.id = table_x.id WHERE member.type = 'x' AND table_x.some_text = 'some text value' 
UNION 
SELECT relation.* FROM relation, UNNEST(relation.members) member INNER JOIN table_y ON member.id = table_y.id WHERE member.type = 'y' AND table_y.some_int = 123 
UNION 
SELECT relation.* FROM relation, UNNEST(relation.members) member INNER JOIN table_z ON member.id = table_z.id WHERE member.type = 'z' AND table_z.some_date > '2017-01-11 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumption

- I´m assuming that `relation.members` array does not have more than one member element of the same type. Correct?

Query to try

```
with unnested_members as (
-- Unnest members array
select id, unnest(members) members
from relation
)
, members_joined as (
-- left join on a per type basis with table_x, table_y and table_z.
select r.id, (r.members).id idext, (r.members).type,
       x.some_text, y.some_int, z.some_date -- more types, more columns here
from unnested_members r
  left join table_x x on (x.id = (r.members).id and (r.members).type = 'x')
  left join table_y y on (y.id = (r.members).id and (r.members).type = 'y')
  left join table_z z on (z.id = (r.members).id and (r.members).type = 'z')
  -- More types, more tables to left join
)
select id,
  max(some_text) some_text, -- use max() to get not null value for this id
  max(some_int) some_int, -- use max() to get not null value for this id
  max(some_date) some_date -- use max() to get not null value for this id
  -- more types, more max() columns here
from members_joined
group by id -- get one row per relation.id with data from joined table_* columns
```

If you need to include more tables then you have to include these tables in the `left join` part, include the column in the `select` list and in the `max()` section as well.

Comment: `relation.members` is an array. It can have multiple members from the same type.